# Jade - convert new lines to <br/> and keep the content encoded

Tags: node.js, pug

I am still not that familiar with the Jade template engine. Is there a way to convert the new lines such as **\n** to **br** tags and at the same time keep the other content encoded?

For example

```
.replace(/\n/g,'</br>')
```

applied over the encoded value should do the work. However I am not sure how to encode the value and get the result. Is there any helper for this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use jades escape method and replace the linebreaks in the return value of that like so:

```
p !{escape(foo).replace(/\n/g, '<br/>')}
```

I am not aware of any built-in functionality for your use case.

---

Looks like pug got rid of the escape function, so this is what you would have to use now:

```
p !{foo.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/\n/g, '<br/>')}
```

Comment: This is what I am talking about! Thanks mate.

Comment: That's not Jade's method. Since template compiles into JS function, you can use any of node and V8 globals inside it.

Comment: While it is true that you can use the global methods, this isn't the global escape method. The global escape method would return `%3C` for each `<` instead of `&lt;` like jades escape method does.

Comment: Trying to format pug error messages in my template, `.message !{message.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>')}` was enough.

Comment: If `message` contains `<`, `>` or `&` those won't be escaped correctly. Apparently with pug escape _is_ the global method so you would have to manually replace above mentioned characters: `.message !{message.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/\n/g, '<br/>')}`

Answer (score 12):

if you don't exactly need `<br>`, you can simply put your text within [**`<pre>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) tag. All whitespaces (including new lines) will be displayed as typed.

Or you could set css rule **`white-space: pre`** to preserve whitespace preformatting. Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) on this.

Comment: Use this in conjuction with `word-wrap: break-word;`

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word` breaks the words up at arbitrary points if there are no acceptable points. If you just want simple text formatting with words wrapping to the next line, try `white-space: pre-wrap`

Comment: Best to use `white-space: pre-line` in this case, I think.

Answer (score 9):

escape method, even converts simple space (' ') characters to "%20".

[MDN says escape is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) and it is meant for encoding strings in url, not html content. 
Another solution,

```
each line in foo.split(/\n/)
  = line
  br
```

Comment: This will leave a trailing newline, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Most answers say you need to do `p !{foo.replace(/\n/g)}`. However, that is not enough: `\n` in regex matches the new line character so you will need to escape the `\` in `\n`. You can do that  by adding a additional `\` to `\n`.


**The final result:**

```
p !{foo.replace(/\\n/g, '<br />')}
```

**NOTE:** If you want to escape the other characters too, you can just add: 
`.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;')`

**EDIT:**
You can use `p #{foo.replace...}` to correctly escape all characters in html tags. This can be useful if you want to prevent users from inserting `<script>...</script>` tags in a input field to hack your website.

Answer (score 1):

Consider whether you really want `<br>` tags.

### If you can use CSS instead

It's better to use `white-space: pre-line`. See the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space), where it says

> `pre-line`
>
> Sequences of white space are collapsed. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

This is the same as the normal behaviour, except that newline characters turn into line breaks.

This ought to do what you want.

### If you want `<br>` tags

All of the existing answers here which give `<br>` tags either don't escape the output for HTML (which can be dangerous), reimplement escaping logic, or leave a trailing newline.

This one is based on [Palani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24478350/496046) but does not leave a trailing newline, and also protects against `foo` being nullish or false.

```
each line in (foo || '').split('\n').slice(0, -1)
  = line
  br
= (foo || '').split('\n').pop()
```

I don't love this solution but I think it's preferable to the others, if you want `<br>` tags.

If you might be putting large strings through it, it might be a good idea to make a temporary variable for the result of the `split` so it's not done twice.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that simple:

```
p !{someString.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>')}
```

Note that this method will correctly escape string.

Comment: it isn't escape the someString variable, and now it can render rich html content, for example xss :(