# Textarea Linebreak in ExpressJS, MongooseJS and Jade

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, pug

In Jade, I have textarea in a form.

```
form(action='save')
    textarea(name='description')
    input(type='submit')
```

Description is saved to mongodb. Im using `mongoosejs` for this.

```
description: String
```

When rendering jade with the `description`, I have:

```
p #{description}
```

What is the best way to display the description with the linebreak.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540788/jade-convert-new-lines-to-br-and-keep-the-content-encoded

Answer (score 2):

There are more ways.

**First way** - is a change of content and replacing for a `<br />`:

```
p !{escape(foo).replace(/\n/g, '<br/>')}
```

**Second way** - You can apply **custom CSS**, so you don't need to replace content and break `\n`

```
<style>
 p { white-space: pre; }
</style>
```

Comment: `p { white-space: pre; }` would not wrap a line. So try use `pre-line` or `pre-wrap` instead. see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp