# node.js and jade: Display content from attribute value - line feeds not displaying

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am quite sure that this could be a simple question, but unfortunately I was not able to find the right answer.
What I have is a database where I have some free text in with \n\r in it for starting new lines. At the moment I am using jade as the framework. When I try to render the pages with the values from the database, the \n\r are not working, as they appear to be just characters that are not interpreted in the html source.

My jade view looks like this:

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 #{doc.recipetitle}
  h3 Zutaten:
  p #{doc.ingredients}
  h3 Anleitung:
  p #{doc.recipe}
  h3 So siehts aus:
  img(src=doc.img)
```

My issues are with the `doc.ingredients` and `doc.recipe`, as this could be values like:
potatotes\r\nbeef\r\nwater\r\n
and it displays to:
potatoes beef water

But what I want is:
potatoes
beef
water

Is it possible to format the paragraph correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You need line breaks to break to next line `<br/>`

You can accomplish this by doing `#{your.param.replace('\r\n', '<br/>')}`

(the replace statement might be different but you hopefully see the concept)

Comment: ok, thanks for the quick help. That does a replacement and if you add a /g it is done for all occurrences. But now my list looks like: potatoes<br />beef<br />water<br />. So not the result I need. When Iook at the source code of the page it looks like: potatotes&lt;br /&gt;beef&lt;br /&gt;water&lt;br /&gt;  Could this be a character set thing?

Comment: Ok, in the end I found the solution. You can find more information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540788/jade-convert-new-lines-to-br-and-keep-the-content-encoded). My correct line in my jade file is now: `p !{doc.ingredients.replace(/\n?\r\n/g, '<br />')}` Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the escape character in the beginning there.  I learned something new as well!