# EJS - convert new lines to <br/> and keep the content encoded

Tags: node.js, ejs

This is similar to [Jade - convert new lines to <br/> and keep the content encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540788/jade-convert-new-lines-to-br-and-keep-the-content-encoded)

so is there easy way to do the same in ejs:

```
<%- escape(foo).replace(/\n/g, '<br/>') %>
```

This could be possible by extracting escape method from ejs and assign to res.locals, but I'm looking for something more elegant if it's possible

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem, when I had to display git commit message in my page. I had a look at how GitLab formats commit messages and found out that they use `white-space: pre-wrap`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

So in my .ejs file I use:

```
<div style="white-space: pre-wrap"><%= commit.body %></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can escape html with `<%= %>`, along with the replace function you already have (assuming `foo` is a string).

```
<%= foo.replace(/\r\n/g, '<br/>')) %>
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but that's not solution since <%= %> encodes angle brackets as well, so output would be "%3Cbr/%3E" instead of "<br/>"

Comment: @Brankodd - I guess I'm not 100% on what is needed (I don't know Jade at all, so it wasn't a translation). You're correct with the `<%=` usage encoding angle brackets. Are you attempting to encode all the characters _then_ replace \r\n with <br/>?

Comment: Yes, the code I pasted in question works (<%- escape(foo).replace(/\n/g, '<br/>') %>), I wanted to check if there is some more elegant solution, but looks like it's best it can be.